# Paramiko exec_command hangs when you SSH from any user other than root

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ssh, permissions, paramiko

So, I have written a small python code which hangs on `exec_command` step when using `support` user and the same works fine while using `root` user

I have no problems running the script from the terminal when logged in as the support user. This is what I am unable to understand why does paramiko.exec_command hangs.

I have tried running the script from windows 10 running python 
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 as well as ubuntu 19.04 running Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

The machine I am trying to ssh is running CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Here is `ls -ltr` on this machine

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 support support 10430264 May 10 12:13 port_check
```

I have tried adding and removing `sudo` from the commands to be executed over SSH and also commenting ssh.invoke_shell()

```
import sys
import paramiko


def pew_print(some_input):
    try:
        some_input = some_input.decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as errors:
        print("Errors : {0}".format(errors))
        pass
    some_input = str(some_input)
    sys.stdout.write(some_input)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()


def ssh_command_output(ssh, command_string):

    # ssh.invoke_shell()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command_string, timeout=90)
    pew_print(stdout.read())


def something(ip_address):

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=ip_address, port=22, username="support", password="pass")
    # ssh_command_output(ssh, "sudo chmod 755 /home/support/port_check")
    # ssh_command_output(ssh, "sudo /home/support/port_check")
    ssh_command_output(ssh, "ls -ltr")
```

I expect the result to be the same when using `support` user when it is using `root` user

EDIT:

`sudo` on support user doesn't require password and I have tried just executing `ls -ltr` from support user and this hangs as well.

I can normally `ssh support@host` and then execute all the above commands

Comment: When you execute sudo, it will expect a password given to gain the sudo privileges. You are not passing that password so the command hangs forever :) the reason it works for root is that the root user always has super user proviliges, no password required.

Comment: @gerwin let me search for how to pass the password. Thanks

Comment: So edit your question to ask for that. If you knew that `sudo` asks for a password, you should have told us from the beginning and not ask such a vague question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have updated the question and I don't think the issue was what gerwin suspected it to be.

Comment: I do not understand your edit. So why do you even mention `sudo` in your question?  + Can you do `ssh support@host ls -ltr` (one line/command)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The point of mentioning sudo was that I have tried executing the commands via sudo as well and normally as well.

And I can execute `ls -ltr` after manually doing `ssh support@host` and then entering in support password. But `ls -ltr` via paramiko still hangs with support user but runs fine with root user

Comment: I was asking, if you can do `ssh support@host ls -ltr` IN ONE LINE, not `ls -ltr` after `ssh support@host`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl actually it hangs. If I run that in a single line.

Comment: Then your server/shell/profile is somehow misconfigured. Not a Python/Paramiko question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Should I delete this question then? Thanks for helping me to find the root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging a bit about the problem. I found out that remote execution is not allowed and hence closing this question.